# Go width of the screen behind main content

Tags: css

Similarly to the way facebook achieve the blue bar at the top, how do I make one bar go the width of the screen (dependent on resolution) but the rest of the content restriction to 1024px.

This is something I have never done before but would like to have a go at.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't put the element inside one with a constrained width.

Comment: How does FB achieve the blue bar but the facebook logo and other links inside the 1024 width?

Comment: Problem if the one with the constrained width is the html-element.

Comment: @Luke add another constrained width element inside the blue bar.

Comment: the blue bar is **NOT** inside the container that's 1024px wide.

Comment: @Luke — with two elements. One with content and one without.

Answer (score 0):

if you setup your HTML like this:

```
<body>
<div class="header site-header">This is my header</div>
<div class="content site-content">This is my content</div>
</body>
```

and your css like this:

```
html, body{margin:0; padding:0;}

.site-header{width:100%; margin:0;}
.site-content{width:1024px; margin:0 auto;}
```

you should be good to go.